# variable type return by php mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, variable-types

I have the below table in my mysql db,

```
    CREATE TABLE deadline_tasks(
    user_id REFERENCES user(user_id),
    task_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    deadline DATE NOT NULL,
    min_chunk_length TIME NOT NULL,
    estimated_time TIME NOT NULL,
    location NOT NULL,
    event_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(task_id)
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id));
```

and I queried the database by using the codes below.

```
$result_tasks = $mysqli->query("SELECT deadline, min_chunk_length, estimated_duration,  
task_id FROM deadline_tasks WHERE user_id = Get[$Name]")
for($deadline_task_from_db = array(); 
$row = $result_tasks->fetch_assoc();
$deadline_tasks_from_db[] = $row);
```

what are the variable types in my array $deadline_task_from_db?

Comment: Given that that your sql has syntax errors, you'll get **NO** "variables" in your array. And if you want to see what's in an array I'd suggest RTFM: http://php.net/print_r and http://php.net/var_dump

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)

Comment: This question makes no sense because the table definition and the query are not about the same table. Any answer would be plain guessing.

Comment: Please check your code and edit your question. Your code has syntax errors. We can't help you if your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
   $result_tasks = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT deadline, min_chunk_length, estimated_duration,  task_id FROM deadline_tasks WHERE user_id = ? ");
    $result_tasks->bind_param('i', Get[$Name]); // Bind "Get[$Name]" to parameter.
                                     ^^^^^^^^--//i dont know if this true variable. Please check it what you mean by it.
    $result_tasks->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $result_tasks->store_result();
    $result_tasks->bind_result($deadline ,$min_chunk_length ,$estimated_duration,$task_id ); // get variables from result.
    while ($row = $result_tasks->fetch()){
        echo $deadline;
        echo $min_chunk_length;
        .........
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the type of a variable in php you can use var_dump
http://www.php.net/var_dump

Answer (score -1):

Use mysqli_fetch_field(), you can get the types under "type" http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-field.php